# Matching multiple dates to a timeline (monthly) for a given project

Tags: excel

My problem is that I have multiple projects that have different dates that pertain to categories and I need a dynamic formula to match those categories by dates to a given timeline.

See [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv3X9.png)

Comment: I can't tell what your data looks like in excel. Maybe post an excel screenshot of what your data currently shows, as well as an excel screenshot of your desired result?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Xlookup should do it!

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(H$1,$B2:$F2,$B$1:$F$1,,0),G2)
```

[image]

v2: This works with looking at the date that represents the end of the period.

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(H$2,$B3:$F3,$B$1:$F$1,,-1),G3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what if my timeline is more of a range and doesn't quite match?

Comment: Please provide a picture of what your dataset looks like. I can't tell what you mean by "more of a range"

Comment: I changed my example. Please take a look. Thank You.